# jQuery focusleave event?

Tags: jquery

Hello i am trying to make a flydown that is accessible bythe keyboard and mouse users. When i hover over or focus on the li i show the fly down navigation. I then use the mouseleave function to close the flyout when i leave the fly down section. I am having trouble doing the same for keyboard users. The blur function isnt working how i want it. I need some sort of a focusleave function similar to mouseleave. Im also trying to build my own example and not use a plugin. Any suggestions?

Here is an example of what i have:

```
<ul id="top-nav-tabs">
      <li class="top-nav-tab">
        <a href="#">Ex1</a>
        <div class="sublevel">
            <ul class="sublevel-nav">
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </li>   <li class="top-nav-tab">
        <a href="#">Ex2</a>
        <div class="sublevel">
            <ul class="sublevel-nav">
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Comment: What have you currently tried?  Where is that JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

[.focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

---

Update: I know you want to roll your own, but I think this focusenterleave plugin is what you're looking for:

> These are to focusin and focusout what mouseenter and mouseleave are to mouseover and mouseout. That essentially means tabbed focussing does not bubble.

- http://enideo.com/code/jquery-events-enter-leave/

Comment: focusout is like mouseout. i want one like mouseleave. If you look at the difference between mouseout and mouseleave you will see what i mean.